# Given a polynomial, prove the set $A$, the pre-image of $\{0\}$, is a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: real-analysis

I already proved that the set $A$ is non empty but showing there was a root value, which is essentially just the set $A$.

Now I have to prove $A$ is a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

I was thinking about the Intermediate Value Theorem. Because the set $A$ consists of the roots of the polynomial, it is a subset of $R$. But I am not sure how to prove it is closed? Am I on the right track here?

Comment: Hint: $p$ is continuous, $\{0\}$ is closed, and $D=p^{-1}(\{0\})$.

Comment: Do you mean you're working with a specific polynomial $p$? The set $D$ is not empty in general (consider $p(x, y) = x^2 + y^2 + 1$). Either way, do you have the topological definition of continuity available?

Comment: Is your polynomial $p:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$?? What definition of continuous do you use?

Comment: I am working with a specific polynomial p:ℝ^2→ℝ. The definition I use is, Let f: A->R, for all p∈A, lim x->p f(x) = f(p)

Answer (score 2):

Polynomials are continuous functions, so in particular, the inverse image of a closed set is closed. We know $D=p^{-1}(\{0\})$, and since $\{0\}$ is a closed set in $\mathbb{R}$, $D$ must be closed in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: Given $D = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid p(x,y) = 0\}$. How do you figure that is the same thing as the pre-image of its roots?

Comment: I think it will help to write down the definition of $p^{-1}(\{0\})$, and then you can try to show than elements in there are always in $D$, and vice versa.

Comment: Didn't understand the downvote, so +1. To be sure @Annie, do you have a working definition for preimage?

Answer (score 1):

Polynomials are continuous, as has been noted previously. I assume familarity with the fact: $f$ is continuous implies that $x_n \to x \implies f(x_n) \to f(x)$. We need a small lemma:

**Lemma:** Let $f$ be continuous and $A$ be closed. Then $f^{-1}(A)$ is also closed.

*proof:* Since $A$ is closed, it contains all of its limit points. Let $a_n \to a$ be a convergent sequence in $f^{-1}(A)$. We show that $a \in f^{-1}(A)$. Since $a_n \to a$, we know that $f(a_n) \to f(a)$, and $f(a) \in A$. by definition, the result follows.

Now for your problem: note that $\{0\}$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}$ .

Comment: Isn't D the set of (x,y) points that make the polynomial equal to 0? So its not just the set {0}

Comment: @Annie No, no. The set of points that make a polynomial $0$, is the same as asking: for what $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ is $p(x,y)=0$. This is the same thing as considering $p^{-1}(\{0\})$. This is why I asked, do you have a working definition of preimage// does this comment make sense to you?

Comment: Okay so would the proof go something like this:
{0} is closed in R, so it contains all of its limit points. Let xn-> x be a convergent sequence in p^-1({0}). Since xn -> x, we know that p(xn)->p(x)...

Comment: Something along those lines. The key observation is that $p$ is continuous. A nice and rigorous proof of this fact can be found here: https://math.berkeley.edu/~kmill/math1afa2014/poly.pdf. From there, it suffices to note that the preimage of closed sets are again closed for continuous functions (1), and you are done . The introduction of the sequential characterization for continuity (in metric spaces) is only there for the proof of (1). Equipped with $p$ is continuous and (1), the proof is a one-liner.